# How do I treat spaces as tabs in SublimeText?

Tags: editor, sublimetext2

I want my files to be saved as 4 spaces per tab.  However, when navigating through the file, I want 4 spaces to be navigated over as if it was a tab.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set `tab_size` equal to 4.

```
// The number of spaces a tab is considered equal to
"tab_size": 4,`
```

and set to `true`

```
// Set to true to insert spaces when tab is pressed
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  When I navigate over the spaces, the editor still treats them as spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to do that without plugins.

I personally use custom binding for navigation and almost never use the arrows, and use command/ctrl/alt + left/right arrows to navigate by words, when you'll get used to this, you'll become very productive. You can then ctrl+right arrow to get from the beginning of the line to the first indented character.

Comment: But if you start at the beginning of the line, doing ctrl+right arrow goes to the end of the first word.

Comment: Sorry, I may be wrong about that, I'm currently on OS X and the keys used to skip indents are `alt+right`. I will see how it's done on windows. Are you still interested in this behaviour? If so I may consider writing a plugin for you

Comment: Yes, I am still interested.  That would be great.